# How to silence or fix snap docker-compose CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported

Tags: snap, docker

My Ubuntu server runs docker installed with [snap](https://snapcraft.io/docker). Recently I noticed that running `docker-compose` brings up a Python related warning, for example:

```bash
$ docker-compose version
/snap/docker/2285/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.6.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

My Python version is higher:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.6
```

And:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        100c70180f
 Built:             Thu Sep 22 06:21:41 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.15
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Thu Sep 22 06:22:13 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I saw a comment on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker-snap/docker-snap/issues/78) about using `pip` to reinstall `docker-compose` but I don't think that would help here since I didn't install it with `pip`:

```
$ pip3 list
Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3-pip

$ pip list
Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

As far as I know, the `docker-compose` plugin is included with the docker snap. For now I just shut it up with:

`alias docker-compose="docker-compose 2>/dev/null"`

But this can hide other errors and I'd prefer an actual fix. Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `docker-compose` is the old, deprecated version of Docker Compose.

Instead, try and run `docker compose version`. This should give you the version of the current release (2.X) of Docker Compose.

You could create an alias to map the old syntax to the new version, like this:

```
alias docker-compose='docker compose'
```

Maybe the old release is included for compatibility, but I would recommend to only use the new 2.X version.

Comment: They should mention the change in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/). Even though they use the newer command and it's even listed in `docker --help`, it's so easy to miss the difference! Better still, they could just remove the old plugin or replace it with a notification.

Thanks, using the new command from now on, it's also nicer!

Comment: Happy to hear it worked for you!  Unfortunately, I see a lot of documentation not being updated to the new syntax, so having the mentioned alias can help a lot.

Comment: For sure, it's helpful, there may be scripts etc. that still use the old syntax. In my case I just used `vim` to replace all my aliases in `.bashrc` that used the old `docker-compose` with `docker compose`.

Comment: Not sure when the change was announced but this post seems to be related: https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-compose-v2-general-availability/